# How To Get Url Parameter Routing Working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The default routing for my ASP.NET Core is as defaulted by VS2015 to be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "default",
   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

When I make my request URL /my-controller/my-special-view it indeed calls the method in my my-control that is defined as follows with the id parameter equal to my-special-value

```
public IActionResult my-controller(string id) {...
```

I'm trying to the same thing with attribute routing.  I define the attribute as follows:

```
[Route("my-controller/{id}")]
public IActionResult my-controller(string id) {...
```

I get an error as follows:

```
InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'attributeOfInterest' - 'string' on the route 'CacheTagHelper/{attributeOfInterest:string}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.
```

I'm not experienced with attritube routing and do not understand why the above to controller methods don't give me the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default routing template is `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`
so you can follow the template in your controller action

the `my-controller` will be your inherited class from `controller` class and the `IActionResult` match with your action method, if you specific the attribute in your put to route the `{Id}` , in your method parameter should also specific the `{Id}`, in routing, you also need to specific the http verb actions(GET,POST, PUT etc)

in your case would be

```
public class my-controller : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public IActionResult my-special-view(String id) { ... }
}
```

Comment: What about your other answer with "FromRoute"?  Specifically, I'm looking for using the route attribute so I can make my template in my controller and not the startup class.

Comment: Using [HttpGet("{id}")] actually caused me problem. For me, [HttpGet] alone worked well. You may want to read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#setting-up-routing-middleware